# Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.2.0 can not work

Tags: jboss, mobicents, restcomm

i start start-restcomm.sh script;

```
[root@WCS restcomm]# screen -list
There are screens on:
        111821.mms      (Detached)
        111830.restcomm (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
the restcomm and mms processes are started,but
netstat -la|grep 8080
netstat -la|grep 8443
```

can not find,

```
screen -r pid
```

only can see the below logs

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/src/src/mobicents/RestComm-master/release/Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2

  JAVA: /usr/java/default/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-sip.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
18:15:37,438 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.CR1
18:15:37,597 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA
18:15:37,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" starting
^C^C18:16:29,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" stopped in 9ms
```

why the ports of the Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss can not establish?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're running JDK 8. RestComm is still using JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final version which doesn't support Java 8. Please use JDK 7 to run RestComm.